# Unable to copy file error

Tags: c#

the program was working fine till after i wrote the last 8 lines, clicked run and then nothing happened (i think i typed something by mistake before clicking run), so i removed the last 8 lines and clicked run it worked. i removed:

```
p.Amount = int.Parse(proAmount.Text);
```

and got this error:

> Could not copy "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed.

and

> Unable to copy file "obj\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe" to "bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe". The process cannot access the file 'bin\Debug\WindowsFormsApp1.exe' because it is being used by another process.

how can i fix this?

Comment: That's a build error. Sounds like you still have your previously run going in the background.

Comment: Close the already running instance of the application. If it is not directly visible then use your task manager and kill any still running instance of that application.

Comment: it's not visible and there is nothing in the task manager

Comment: Have you tried restarting?

Comment: these are the lines causing the problem : p.Amount = int.Parse(proAmount.Text);
            
            lvi2 = new ListViewItem(p.PID.ToString());
            lvi2.SubItems.Add(p.Kind);
            lvi2.SubItems.Add(p.Type);
            lvi2.SubItems.Add(p.Name);
            lvi2.SubItems.Add(p.Amount.ToString());

            prolistview.Items.Add(lvi2);

Comment: i tried restarting the  software and the pc still the same

Comment: :) there was a windows error reporting window open i closed it and it worked. but it's still not running when i add the line in the question.and open windows error reporting window. i used the similar code in 5 other lines i don't know why this one is causing it to not run

Comment: guys how can i delete this post? it was a stupid mistake sorry i'm tired and sleepy and was the dumbest mistake ever .

Comment: Click Delete under your question.

Comment: i don't know if someone can learn something from this but i was calling the wrong name and the code was in the wrong method :), stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error usually occurs when you try to run/build you application and you've not closed an already running instance of the application. The build tries to overwrite the .exe file but it cant since it is running.

Are you absolutely sure you closed all instances of the application? Otherwise try manually removing the .exe file from the /bin/Debug folder and build again.

You can also try "Clean" from the Build menu and see if that helps.

Comment: you think i should leave this post?

Comment: It's most likely best to delete it if it was a mistake and if no one else will benefit from your question.

Comment: looks like i can't delete it cause some people answered on it